# Google Geocoder API Requests Exceeded

Tags: php, google-maps

I am using Google Geocoder API.

I am aware that its Quota for 24 Hour Period is 2,500 Requests.

But my needs are way huge than this limit.

What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The quota is as you said, 2'500 requests / 24hour / client user, which is huge. However, with Google Maps API for Business, there is a 100,000 requests per 24 hour period, but of course, it isn't a free service.

Comment: @CodeHunter no, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/ for more info